# How to proceed with this limit (Hôpital rule and sgn function)

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, trigonometry

Though the verification (or not) of the hypotheses of Hôpital theorem, I want to calculate the limit:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \sqrt{\dfrac{x^2}{\sin(x)}}$$

**My procedure**

First of all, I recognise that I can write:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{|x|}{\sqrt{\sin(x)}}$$

The hypothesis by which the form must be $0/0$ is then checked.

Now, the two functions must be differentiable in $(a, b) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, and I observe that $|x|$ is not differentiable at $0$, whilst $\sqrt{\sin(x)}$ is not differentiable at $x = k\pi$ for $k$ integer.

I need to consider that $\sin(x)$ must be postive too.

With an opportune interval, I can then verify that both functions are differentiable.

Now the condition $g'(x) \neq 0$ in $(a, b)$ means $\frac{\cos(x)}{2\sqrt{\sin(x)}}\neq 0$ which happens for $x \neq \frac{(2k + 1)\pi}{2}$.

So I can build a subdomain $\bar{\Omega} = \left(0, \dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)$ where to study the limit.

That being said, the condition is checked.

Lastly, I have to verify that the limit fo the derivaties exists (finite or infinite), and here I got stuck. I indeed have:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{|x|}{\sqrt{\sin(x)}} = \lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{2 \text{sgn}(x) \sqrt{\sin(x)}}{\cos(x)} = \lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{2|x| \sqrt{\sin(x)}}{x \cos(x)}$$

I know that the sine is zero, the cosine is one, but what is sgn$(x)$ at zero? I found that someone say it's zero, others say it's undefined, others say it's one.

Since I have $\sqrt{\sin(x)}$, could I say I'm "protected" and the limit is zero?

I also think the limit is zero because the absolute value goes to zero "better" than $\sqrt{\sin(x)}$, where better means rapider for $\sqrt{\sin(x)} \approx \sqrt{x}$ in this range.

Some help?

Comment: The limit is not well defined for $x \to 0^{-}$ since $x^2/\sin(x) < 0$.

Comment: @sudeep5221 Oh, I really didn't pay attention to that... Square root + sine, right. So at $0$ the limit doesn't exist, right? If it were $x\to 0^+$ would I be right instead?

Comment: The easiest way is if you know $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1.$ Then $$\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{\sin x}}=\dfrac {\sqrt x}{\sqrt{\frac{\sin x}{x}}}\to \sqrt{\frac01}=0$$ as $x\to0^+.$

Comment: Your argument reference $g$ and $g'$ a lot without telling us what it is. Presumably, the denominator from L'Hopital? But you don't need $g'(0)$ defined in that case, only the limit of $f'(x)/g'(x)$ as $x\to 0.$

Comment: In general, to find $\lim_{x\to 0}\sqrt{h(x)}$ (or $x\to 0^+$ or $x\to 0^-$) you only need that $h(x)$ is non-negative in some $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\setminus\{0\}$ (or $(0,\epsilon)$ or $(-\epsilon,0)$ for the directional limits) and then you need to know $\lim h(x)=L.$  Then you'll have $$\lim\sqrt{h(x)}=\sqrt L.$$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $x\to0^+,$ $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=\sqrt{\sin x}$ and you have $f(x)\to0$ and $g(x)\to 0$ as $x\to0^+.$

Now, $f'(x)=1$ and $g'(x)=\frac{\cos x}{2\sqrt{\sin x}}$ for $x\in(0,\pi/2).$

So L'Hopital applies and:

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{x}{\sqrt {\sin x}}=\lim_{x\to0^+}\dfrac{1}{\frac{\cos x}{2\sqrt{\sin x}}}=\lim_{x\to0+}\frac{2\sqrt{\sin x}}{\cos x}=0.$$

You don't need $g'(0)$ defined, or even $\lim_{x\to0^+} g'(x)$ to exist. You just need to know the limit of $f'(x)/g'(x)$ and that L'Hopital applies.

Comment: For what I knew about Hôpital theorem, I need to have $f, g$ both differentiable in $(a, b)$, then IF $g'(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in (a, b)$, IF $\lim_{x\to a^+} f/g$ has the form $0/0$ or $\infty/\infty$ and IF $\lim_{x\to a^+} f'/g'$ exists, THEN $$\lim_{x\to a^+} f/g = \lim_{x\to a^+} f'/g'$$

Same speech holds for $b^-$
Hence I thought I had to build the interval $(a, b)$ and verufy all the hypotheses.

Comment: I also just noticed that since I only can evaluate it at $0^+$, there is no absolute value indeed...